# R grep(): How to search for letter "l"?

Tags: r

I have a problem with R's grep() function apparently finding an "l" everywhere:

```
    > l <- list(list(), list("a"), list("a","l"))
    > grep("a",l)
    [1] 2 3
    > grep("l",l)
    [1] 1 2 3
    > grep("l",l,fixed=TRUE)
    [1] 1 2 3
```

This problem seems to occur only with the letter "l". Does anyone have a hint on that?

Many thanks,
   Cord

Comment: What is the desired result?

Comment: Actually the indices of the sublists containing the pattern

Comment: `rapply(l,function(x)grep("l",x),how="list")` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the documentation for the argument `x` in `grep` you'll see that it should be

> a character vector where matches are sought, or an object which can be coerced by as.character to a character vector.

If you try that operation you'll see what goes wrong:

```
> as.character(l)
[1] "list()"             "list(\"a\")"        "list(\"a\", \"l\")"
```

so the same "problem" happens if you grep for `i`, `s` etc.

You could try the following instead

```
sapply(l, function(i) grep("l", i))
```

which produces

```
[[1]]
integer(0)

[[2]]
integer(0)

[[3]]
[1] 2
```

Comment: This brought me onto the right track - I just had to embed the sapply(...) into a which() call: which(sapply(...)!=0)

Answer (score 0):

Interesting post, I never knew `grep` convert the `x` vector like this:

```r
l <- list(list(), list("a"), list("a","l"))
l
#> [[1]]
#> list()
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> [[3]][[2]]
#> [1] "l"
```

Internally grep is converting l to a character vector

```r
grep
#> function (pattern, x, ignore.case = FALSE, perl = FALSE, value = FALSE, 
#>     fixed = FALSE, useBytes = FALSE, invert = FALSE) 
#> {
#>     if (!is.character(x)) 
#>         x <- structure(as.character(x), names = names(x))
#>     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#>     .Internal(grep(as.character(pattern), x, ignore.case, value, 
#>         perl, fixed, useBytes, invert))
#> }
#> <bytecode: 0x0000000012e18610>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

So now l is actually:

```r
structure(as.character(l), names = names(l))
#> [1] "list()"             "list(\"a\")"        "list(\"a\", \"l\")"
```

Which has "l" in each.

You could unlist l first to get expected results:

```r
ul <- unlist(l)
ul
#> [1] "a" "a" "l"

grep("a",l)
#> [1] 2 3

grep("a",ul)
#> [1] 1 2

grep("l",l)
#> [1] 1 2 3

grep("l",ul)
#> [1] 3

grep("l",l,fixed=TRUE)
#> [1] 1 2 3

grep("l",ul,fixed=TRUE)
#> [1] 3
```

Comment: Unlist does not help me because the information on the sublists is lost.